# How to configure Hive warehouse path?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I modified this part

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

of `hive-default.xml.template` with my own path. When running hive, if I try to create a table it says it could create file://mypath/etc.. and it is still looking for `/user/hive/warehouse`. Did I do something wrong? I tried to create hive-site.xml, and it does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the warehouse path in **hive-site.xml** as follows:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>Your_Path_HERE</value>
  <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

Give the permission to `<Your_Path_HERE>` directory if it is on local system

```
sudo chown -R user <Your_Path_HERE>
sudo chmod -R 777 <Your_Path_HERE>
```

if given path is on HDFS , then stop and start the hadoop services

```
stop-all.sh
start-all.sh
```

Comment: I'm using hdfs path.I have configured hive-site.xml. I have given permissions to hdfs path. I'm using below code conf = SparkConf().setAppName("sample").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("show databases").show(). I'm unable to see the databases that are in my hive warehouse.

Comment: create hive context. System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "url of metastore"); val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext);

Answer (score 0):

You have specify the property in `hive-site.xml`:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/user/hivestore/warehouse </value>
</property>
```

And once modified try reloading the hive shell by exiting and starting hive-shell.

Also, make sure that everyone using hive have appropriate **read/write permissions** to the the directory specified in the above property.