# Apache default Hive Warehouse path in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I installed HIVE on CentOS 7 3-node cluster the first time for POC purpose. HIVE is installed inside a user(hduser1)'s root folder and specified in the .bashrc file.

export HIVE_HOME=/home/hduser1/hive

I also created an HDFS folder for HIVE warehouse, with the following commands.

hadoop   fs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop   fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse

Everything works fine. After I created a table, I saw a file appearing in the warehouse folder.

Here is my question - how does HIVE know about this warehouse path, considering that I did not add this path /user/hive/warehouse in any configuration file?

I saw another person's installation, which created the Hive warehouse folder at /user/hive234/warehouse and that installation still worked. Does HIVE figure it out by some naming convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you know that default location is maintain as /user/hive/warehouse, But you can change location as well, by specifying the desired directory in hive.metastore.warehouse.dir configuration parameter present in the hive-site.xml, one can change this default location.
 [Here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812408/how-to-configure-hive-warehouse-path?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I've been looking for.